# Ansible: "become" when user is sudoer with 'NOPASSWD'

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to execute a 'git' task on a remote machine as a different user.
I log in to the machine as my user, which is a sudoer with NOPASSWD.

here the gist of the Ansible play

```
- name: my play
  remote_user: francesco
  tasks:
    - name: pull repo
      become: yes
      become_user: machine_user
      git: ...
```

with 'become: yes' I get an error with missing become password (which I assume is the sudo password for user 'francesco'), without 'become: yes' i get permission denied error, so I think the git task is not executed as 'machine_user'

Comment: this works fine for me. i would confirm that you can password-less `sudo` on the box to be absolutely certain. it would also help if you ran with `-vvvv` and show the error about missing become password. also, what version of ansible are you using?

Comment: here's the verbose output https://gist.github.com/fdellavedova-rocket/4c765550563a29b5097d

Comment: the only way I can replicate this is if my `sudoers` is missing (modified for your case) `francesco ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`. `ssh` to that host and try to run a command, i.e. `sudo date`. if it prompts for password then you know.

Comment: I ssh'd to the machine and run sudo date... no password asked. Also here is the relevant line from /etc/sudoers:
    
    francesco ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when I had a user added to the 'sudo' group and the sudo group did not need password; when adding that user individually with the same exact same configuration, it worked without a hitch.

If your user gets it's permissions from a group, I'd suggest switching to configuring permissions on the user instead.