Ansible still asking for sudo with a passwordless user
I have just started learning ansible , i configured a simple playbook where m running a apt install command using a passwordless remote user (called ansible) and added the become:true as shown in the code below.
---

- name: managig the ubuntu servers
  hosts: ubuntu_servers
  remote_user: ansible
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Installing a pcakage on ubuntu servers
      apt:
        name: traceroute
        state: present
        update_cache: true

I am positive that the user ansible is configured as a passwordless sudoer , since I've tested it directly on the servers , but m alwasy getting this error

fatal: [server2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}

fatal: [server3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}

How is the user configured for sudo? Individually or using a group? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33913875/21105992

@teapot418 it's actually quite the opposite when configuring the user individually ( by adding this line ansible ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL) it didn't work
but after adding the NOPASSWD to the sudo group it worked fine, though that's not the behaviour m asking for , i just need the ansible user to be a passwordless sudoer

i tried to create a group and setting it to be passwordless sudoers group and then i added ansible to it ,  on the remote server the user  is indeed a passwordless sudoer , but i still get the same error from ansible.

I think the issue comes from the remote_user. You specified remote_user in the hosts context, but seems like it doesn't work. I did some small test:
default group in inventory file
<server name> ansible_host=<host ip> ansible_user=jenkins ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'

my playbook
---
- name: test
  hosts: default
  remote_user: wvcuser
  tasks:
    - name: whoami
      shell: whoami
      register: output

    - debug:
        var: output.stdout

The output:
...
ok: [devserver1] => {
    "output.stdout": "jenkins"
}
...

A stratforward way is to use ansible_user. So, you have to check the ansible_user in your inventory file is "ansible", or make it sudo-able
